# how to copy data from one worksheet to another?

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

i have a problem in hand.I goto copy information from a worksheet say "sheet1" to "sheet2" but the catch here is i goto copy only certain fields.say for example i have

### S.no Name  ID Class

1  Jhon  12 10

---

2  peter 13 9

in the second worksheet i goto copy only sno and id..and the position of these are not fixed,columns maybe inserted in the middle.

I tried to select entire row and choose the values i want.But it isnt working

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: To select disjoined cells, try using hold CTRL and LeftClick - either on individual cells or to select entire column click on column name, e.g.:"A"

Answer (score 0):

You could look up the correct header to find the right column:

```
Sub copyNoAndID()
    Dim noRange As Range, idRange As Range
    Set noRange = Range("A1:Z1").Find("S.no")
    Set idRange = Range("A1:Z1").Find("ID")

    noRange.Resize(1000).Copy Range("AA1")
    idRange.Resize(1000).Copy Range("AB1")
End Sub
```

Whatever the position of your columns the lookup will identify them and copy them side by side.

Comment: Thanks mate!.First part of code to find the headers is working cool.Can You explain what resize function does here?..I am kinda new to vba..so i might not understnd few basics.

Comment: The Resize function returns the range corresponding to the extension of a range over a certain number of rows and columns: e.g. Range("A1").Resize(2, 3) is "A1:C2" because you extend over 2 rows and 3 columns.